# While creating components on ember. Skipping .js file?

Tags: ember.js

If i run below, comment for generating component in ember.

```
$ ember generate component my-new<br>
installing component<br>
  create app\components\my-new.hbs<br>
  **skip app/components/my-new.js<br>**
  tip to add a class, run ember generate component-class my-new <br>
installing component-test <br>
  create tests\integration\components\my-new-test.js<br>
```

It doesn't create both componentName.js and template files.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, it's the default behavior in Ember since Glimmer template-only components were introduced. To fix it you should add one of `--component-class` options, e.g.

`ember generate component my-new --component-class @glimmer/component`

or, use an alias `ember generate component my-new -gc`.

The full list of options available could be retrieved by calling `ember help g`

Comment: If see the old versions blueprints. Another component file is also generated. app>templates>component>name.hbs. But for me that's not generated? Why.

Comment: @Dhanabal because that changed with [template co-location](https://emberjs.github.io/rfcs/0481-component-templates-co-location.html). You now have `/app/components/name.hbs` and (optional) `/app/components/name.js`. You can also have `/app/components/name/index.hbs` and (optional) `/app/components/name/index.js`. for this pass `-ns` to `ember g component`. The old structure still works but you should start moving to this new structure.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in the output

```
 tip to add a class, run ember generate component-class my-new <br>
```

In your terminal, wherever you just typed `ember generate component my-new`, type `ember generate component-class my-new`

This will create the backing `my-new.js` file for your component.

In Ember Octane, a component doesn't require a backing `.js` file anymore so the default generator does not create one.

Alternatively, you could manually create the `my-new.js` file in your components directory with `touch` or copying an existing component. I can't tell you exactly where the file would go since you may / may not be colocating, using pods, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use either

```
ember generate component -gc my-component
```

to generate a glimmer component or

```
ember generate component -cc my-component
```

However notice that you *not always need a `.js` file. A component with just an `.hbs` is totally valid and even more performant (if you dont actually need the `.js`).

Comment: If you don't use a .js how do you run javascript on it. Doesn't it mean it's just a html file?